# In spark 2.1, how come the dataframe.createOrReplaceTempTable does not replace an existing table?

Tags: apache-spark

I am caching dataframes so that I can retrieve them later without reading from disk. After I do a transformation on a dataset, I want to update it in the cache.
I cache a dataframe like this:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView(uniqueName)
sqlContext.cacheTable(uniqueName)
```

The Storage tab of spark UI shows a single entry with my specified uniqueName and size of 63.7KB.
Now I transform the dataframe (by adding a column) and cache it again the same way.

There are now two entries in the storage tab (for tables with the same uniqueName) when I expected to see only one. The first entry has size 65.2KB and represents the transformed dataframe. The one listed underneath it represents the first one (63.7KB).

I thought that maybe the storage tab shows tables that are cached and not just registered views, so I tried calling

```
sqlContext.uncacheTable(uniqueName)
```

right before I called the above two lines to cache a dataframe.
It does not change the fact that 2 tables will show in the storage tab after the second call to df.createOrReplaceTempView(uniqueName).

Next I thought I would try calling

```
   if (sqlContext.tableNames().contains(uniqueName)) {
      sqlContext.dropTempTable(uniqueName)
   }
```

right before calling the two lines to cache the dataframe. This works to remove the duplicate row in the storage tab, but the moment I try to use the cached table (like count the number of rows), I get an exception like

```
ERROR he.spark.executor.Executor [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/sql-context] - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 42)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Malformed line in FAILFAST mode: No Braund, Mr. Owen Harris male    22.0    A/5 21171       7.25   ?3       S       1       0       4
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:166)
```

It looks like it is failing to read the first line of the cached dataframe because it contains the additional column, and its not expecting that for some reason.
Why isn't createOrReplaceTempView actually replacing a view with the same name? Should I file a bug, or am I not understanding how the API works?

I've reviewed the [CachedTable tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/CachedTableSuite.scala), but I do not see a test that verifies that createOrReplaceTempView will replace a view that already esists.

Comment: I can avoid the FAILFAST error above by adding a Thread.sleep(2000) after the call to sqlContext.dropTempTable(uniqueName), but that should not be necessary. It seems that the call to dropTempTable happens asynchronously, and there is no reliable way to know when it is done. What am I missing?

Comment: I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19699 for this.

Comment: Every found an explanation for this?